# Prompt user for parameters in Reporting Service 2005

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using ReportExecution2005.asmx service to execute report on report server and serve user with HTML of rendered report. I am setting the parameters programmatically but if i don't provider parameters,  report crashes that parameter is not specified. What i want to do is to prompt the user for parameters if they are not provided. Prompt on parameters is on. Here is my source;

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = "http://server/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

        // Render arguments
        byte[] result = null;
        string reportPath = "/Test reports/DemoReport";
        string format = "HTML4.0";
        string historyID = null;
        string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

        // Prepare report parameter.
        ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[2];
        parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
        parameters[0].Name = "CompanyName";
        parameters[0].Value = "ASDA";
        parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
        parameters[1].Name = "ProgramID";
        parameters[1].Value = "6"; 

        DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
        string showHideToggle = null;
        string encoding;
        string mimeType;
        string extension;
        Warning[] warnings = null;
        ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;

        ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
        String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID);


        try
        {
            result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();

            Console.WriteLine("Execution date and time: {0}", execInfo.ExecutionDateTime);


        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
        }
        // Write the contents of the report to an MHTML file.
        try
        {
            FileStream stream = File.Create("report.mht", result.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("File created.");
            stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.");
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```